# Rebase a branch after submitting part of it for review

Tags: git

Suppose we have this situation

```
   M  <-  A  <-  B  <-  C
   ^                    ^
master                 foo
```

where `A`, `B`, and `C` are somewhat unrelated changes we have made while working in some line of development.
Now we would like to submit your code for review (say on github's pull request system).
We do not want to submit `A`, `B`, and `C` all at the same time because they're not directly related.

We can make a new branch called `PR_a` at `A`

```
   M  <-  A  <-  B  <-  C
   ^      ^             ^
master  PR_a           foo
```

and then submit `PR_a` for review/pull request.
However, during review, we may change things according to feedback, essentially transforming `A` into a modified commit `A'`.
Therefore, once we have merged the work into master we will have

```
M  <----- A'
  \       ^
   \    master
    \
     <--- A <- B <- C
                    ^
                   foo
```

Now we may wish to rebase `foo` off of `master` so that we can keep our history clean, or move on to submitting `B` for review.
If we just do

```
git checkout foo
git rebase -i master
```

we may have conflicts if `A` and `A'` differ substantially.

Is there a way to avoid having to deal with merge conflicts in this workflow?

N.B. In general one should avoid unrelated changes in a branch.
Branches ought to be short lived and directed toward a single bug fix or feature.
However, some times this situation does come up and it is useful to understand how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing

```
git checkout foo
git rebase -i master
```

we are presented with an editor window listing all the commits from `foo` which git will try to add after `master` [1]:

```
pick A <commit message for A>
pick B <commit message for B>
pick C <commit message for C>
```

Since master already has `A'`, we don't need `A` here, so delete it!
Just remove the first line with commit `A`, save the file, and exit the editor.
The rebase will now go off without a hitch now unless `B` and/or `C` touch the same code as `A`.

[1] See [the docs on git rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for more details.